# JSF2 Primefaces polling different xhtml pages inside a div?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to use polling to render different xhtml pages with different backing beans inside a div with Primefaces?

Comment: Please elbortate?Do You mean to say that you have different xhtml pages included in a div and you want to render them using backing bean?

Comment: @freak What I mean is that I want to render different xhtml pages one at a time with a defined set of intervals. eg. render page1 inside a div for 5 seconds then render page2 for 5 seconds then page3 5 seconds in a loop with each of the pages having different backing beans.

Answer (score 1):

Updating bean values in a loop is not a correct logic because it will not update the page/div. You have refresh your div after a specific interval and at its refreshing time , you will update those values.I suggest you to use [primefaces ajax pool](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf) for this through which you can refresh you div after desired interval.

```
 <p:poll interval="3"   
    listener="#{renderBean.updatePagename}" update="whatEverYouWantToUpdate" />
```

Here in listener you can update your bean values and can settle your rendering logic

Another way is , You can refresh your div after every 5 secs using jquery
Now the thing is , you need to capture the refresh event which can be easily captured by javascript
here is a short example for this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var autoRefresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_div').load('record_mypage').fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

<body>
<div id="load_div"> </div>
</body>

</script>
```

Now here you will update the bean values on every refresh and the page will be updated in your desired div.

Comment: but doesnt this only update the values of the current xhtml on that div?  Also everytime a new xhtml is loaded into the target div that new xhtml has a different backing bean from what it replaced.